# IIS Localhost Asp Net MVC application trows Erro 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I am no longer able to connect to my Asp NET mvc 4 application running on IIS7.5

I have made no change at all and after a computer restart I am getting:

```
Erro 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

I am trying to access it from localhost. The application still been developed so I don´t understand why it is happening.

Following instructions I have already done:

- Checked IIS services
- Re-configured IIS for this application
- Flushed DNS
- Disabled Windows Firewall

Is there somenthing else I should look at???
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

For some reason I have might removed the localhost certificate used in the application.

I created a new self-signed certificate, and added it to IIS. Last step was to add this certificate in the application SSL configuration.

That´s all!

Comment: Same... I didn't touch the settings of the site that was having problems, but for some reason it removed my self-signed cert. Not sure why